# Register/Login popup form for WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, forms, facebook-login, user-registration

Hi I'm building a site using the WPTUBE4 theme in WordPress. I'd put the link but I'm creating it on my localhost using WebMatrix. My issue is i can't get a register/login popup form to work. I just want to have a button or link in my header that says Login and another that says Register and when you click have a form popup in a "lightbox" lets say and then the user can Register using their email and a password like most other sites have. Then from then on they can just login to the site. To complicate it a bit more I would like to set up a "log in using facebook option" much like how StackOverflow has. I've just been having a hard time finding the right tutorial or plugin online and I'm hoping that this newbie question can be answered and/or someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks and sorry for it being such a simple thing to ask. Not sure if i should be using jQuery for this or something like it, I might just redirect to another page with the form there but i wanted to avoid this, i wanted to keep users on the same page and just overlay (Lightbox effect) the form then when they're done they could return to exactly where they were. Regardless of what i use i would like to learn the skill to use both. Thanks.

Comment: This [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simplemodal-login/) may help

Comment: Thanks Phil I'll have a go at that. I'm just going to setup a registration/sign up page and either a login page or use one of the plugins or hand code to make a login at the header until i feel comfortable with what i would really like to do.